# Find out Hasse diagram for the relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I have following set $M =\{0,1,2\}$ and relation $R = \leq \{(x,y) \in M \times M, x \leq y \}$. I found out, that $R$ on $M$ is partially ordered set. Now I have to construct Hasse diagram for the mentioned relation.

I know, that R consists of elements $(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,1), (1,2), (2,2)$. How will the diagram look like ?

Final diagram:
The green arrows represent Hasse diagram, the red arrows had to be removed from original graph.

[image: Hasse Diagram]

Comment: The Hasse diagram is on the $3$ elements of $M$.

Comment: @saulspatz But will the diagram contain just 3 elements? I mean that, can I make vertices like vertex (0,0), then vertex (0,1) and so on, or will the elements (0,0), (0,1), ... represent edges between vertices ?

Comment: You could write the relation more concisely as $R = {\leq}$. That is: the relation $R$ is exactly the relation $\leq$.

Comment: Yes, sure. I can edit my post. But is there somebody who has an answer to my problem?

Comment: Do you know what a Hasse diagram is? First try drawing a graph with as vertices the elements of your partial order (i.e. elements of $M$), where you draw an arrow between any two elements that are related by the relation (i.e. if $(x,y)\in R$, then you draw an arrow $x\to y$). To get the Hasse diagram, you remove any arrows that can be deduced from reflexivity or transitivity, and then you simply make sure to position the vertices of the graph such that all of the remaining arrows point upwards.

Comment: If you do it right, your Hasse diagram should have just two arrows.

Comment: I edited my post. The red arrows are removed from diagram. Do the green arrows represent a Hasse diagram?

Comment: Yes, that's completely correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for help :)

Comment: Is $R = \leq$ supposed to mean something?

Comment: That is not a Hasse diagram. It is the diagram of a graph.

Comment: @WilliamElliot read more carefully.  The op acknowledges this and is asking if the graph containing only the green edges is a hasse diagram after having removed the red edges.